# ruby regex match from end of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I've read somewhere today that regex tag in SO gets most "give me ze code" type questions, so I was cautious in asking... I tried, but if this is a duplicate please let me know so I can delete.

```
[First]sometext[Second]
```

I would like to use Regex in Ruby to return value between second []:

```
Second
```

I so far have:

```
(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])
```

which returns

`First]sometext[Second`

```
\[.*?(\[)
```

this grouping will return

```
[First]sometext[
```

so I've been struggling to somehow mix the two but no luck.. hope someone can help.

The closest reference I can find in SO was searched with "match second or nth occurence in regex" which I couldn't get it to work on my issue.

my workaround was to use gsub to replace the `[First]` with "" to the initial string with:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

and then do another match.. but I would like know how it can be done with on regex usage.

Comment: `.*\[(.*?)\]` will start searching from the beginning and gobble up as much as possible until it can match (the last instance of) [...].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> s = "ipsum[First]sometext[Second]lorem"
=> "ipsum[First]sometext[Second]lorem"
> s =~ /\[.*?\].*?\[(.*?)\]/
=> 5
> $1
=> "Second"
```

Comment: Thanks! I now have `.match(regex)` and another line calling it with `x = $1` is it possible to do it in one line? something like `x = .match(regex),$1` ?

Comment: Rok, yes: `s[/\[.*?\].*?\[(.*?)\]/,1] #=> "Second"`.  See [String#[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a greedy search at the beginning `.*` so capture as much as possible?

```
^.*\[(.*?)\]
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/Pq9xPEwSZt)

You could then make it un-greedy (to capture only the stuff in the first [...] block) by appending `?` as   `^.*?`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of ways to handle this. One that hasn't been mentioned yet is the end of input anchor `$`.

```
s = "[First]sometext[Second]"
s.match(/[\[][^\[]+[\]]$/)  # => #<MatchData "[Second]">
s.match(/[\[]([^\[]+)[\]]$/)  # => #<MatchData "[Second]" 1:"Second">
```

This only works in the specific case where `[something]` ends your string.

The section on 'anchors' describes the subtle differences between `$` and `\z` and `\Z`.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Use this to capture the relevant section in the first capturing group, then access it with `$1`

`.*?\[.*?\[(.*?)\].*`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that may be more convenient if you just want the text enclosed by the last `[..]` in a string that may contain any number of `[..]`'s. **[Edit:** I'll leave this, but @OnlineCop has a better solution for the objective I described in the previous sentence.  It's also an excellent answer to the original question.**]**

Reverse the string, then search for a substring with a regex that captures `]` in the non-capture group `(?:\])`, captures `*.?` in capture group 1 (the `?` making it non-greedy) and captures `[` in a second non-capture group.  Lastly, retrieve and reverse the string contained in capture group 1:

```
str = "The [first] time I was mad.  The [second] time I was irate!"
str.reverse[/(?:\])(.*?)(?:\[)/,1].reverse #=> "second"
```